# What is the name for a single item of hundreds and thousands

Tags: grammatical-number

I was wondering what the singular term for `hundreds and thousands` was. I believe in the United States these are referred to as `sprinkles` and `a sprinkle` makes sense in this case. However `a hundred and thousand` sounds a bit awkward.

I have attached an image below in case there was any confusion.

[image: hundreds and thousands]

Comment: I can't think that *sprinkles* is any easier to work with, in language terms, than *hundreds and thousands*. A sprinkle of sprinkles? What would 'a sprinkle be', a few that were 'sprinkled', or just one?

Comment: I would say that the phrase "I ate a sprinkle" would be fine where as with hundreds and thousands there is still trouble. Herein lies my problem!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Something like I ate a MOLE of sprinkles?

Comment: A mole of sprinkles would definitely be much more than a single one - but I love the attempt :)

Comment: A *hunsand*? A *thoudred*?

Comment: Do people actually call sprinkles "hundreds and thousands"? As in "I'd like a donut with hundreds and thousands on it, please."? If so... I guess *why* would be my question.

Comment: If I get what you're talking about I've never heard them called "hundreds and thousands" in the US.  Almost always "sprinkles", but the term "non-pareils" is sometimes used, apparently for a specific subclass of "sprinkles".  There are also names like "Decorettes" and "Dragees", which may be trade names, plus "dust" and "glitter", which are slightly different categories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Hundreds and thousands' is a plural-form non-singular noun, not having a generally accepted term for the individual element. If you were skilful enough to drop just one, you'd say 'I've dropped one' unless you were feeling whimsical. There are parallels: with confetti, the word 'confetto' exists, but it's probably hardly ever used for the bit-of-paper sense. The singular form 'an oat' is rare.

Mass nouns usually take singular concord (milk is / sand is ...), but may be etically discrete (sand) or non-discrete (milk).

The problem 'discrete referent treated grammatically as having no singular' is discussed in [this article by Anna Wierzbicka](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=50tKm3QCaf8C&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=%22hundreds+and+thousands%22+mass+noun&source=bl&ots=E-CP8wfvJf&sig=Gv1hZTbeaGS0ANMQHiFfbmnTW4c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fdM_VPehGOaS7Abi-4H4Aw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hundreds%20and%20thousands%22%20mass%20noun&f=false).

Comment: So what you're saying is I need to create one? How does `a hundron` sound?

Comment: Billions (of people) have survived without having such a term. In fact, many without the delights of hundreds and thousands. Why do you need to create a term? (Looks like a bacillus to me, but I'd avoid that one.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So what you're saying is hundreds and thousands of people have survived long enough without such a term?

Comment: I think I'm resigned to the fact that there is no current term for one, I guess I'd like there to be one as I'm personifying these little pieces of sugar too much. That said it will not stop my campaign for them to be individually acknowledged in their own right! Great answer :)

Answer (score 3):

A single [hundreds and thousands](https://www.google.com/search?q=hundreds+and+thousands) is   a *nonpareil*.

Edit: or just a *one*. Because of course it is.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got it.  You're going to like this: a ***lakh***:

[image: Google definition of "lahk"]

Don't believe me?  How about [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh):

> *A **lakh** or **lac** is a unit in the South Asian numbering system equal to **one** hundred thousand.*

Or [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lakh):

> *lahk: **one** hundred thousand*

Emphasis, of course, on the ***one*** :)

Comment: That doesn't really work. In that case, why not call it a 'mil' (Spanish for 1k) or a 'sen'(Japanese for 1k) or a 'man'(Japanese for 10k)?
What the questions is asking is for something in ENGLISH that represents a hundred units, like the Spanish word 'ciento'

Comment: No, the point is that the units desired is a hundred-thousand: 1e5 (and also that lahk/lac is a nice, short, crisp word).

Comment: Only it's not an English word.

Comment: It's English enough to be in English-language dictionaries.

Comment: The OP is looking for the singular of a nonpareil or sprinkle that the collective noun in BrE is called a "hundreds and thousands". The use case would be similar to "Do you want some *hundreds and thousands* on your cupcake?" with a response of "I would like just one green [term fills here]."

Comment: @SrJoven I know, I'm suggesting *lahk* (or, in my preference, *lac*) for that term. Since the multitude are known as "*hundreds and thousands*", one might like to refer to a single item as "***one** hundred thousand*". Get it?

Comment: @DanBron :) :) ok :) gotcha

Comment: @DanBron but it wouldn't be a hundred thousand to answer the question, right? More like a hundred thousandth? ;) or actually just *one*. :)

Comment: @SrJoven: the idea is if many of them are  "*foos*", then one, alone, is simply "*a foo*"; in this case, "*foo*" is "*hundred thousand*". In other words, the pun is treating the candy name as an opaque, **plural**, string, and explicitly *not* unpacking it. Dig? That said, "*one*" is a pretty hilarious answer too! (But mathematically "*hundred-thousandth*" would *not* work, because then the multitude would be simply "*one*", I.e. a whole passel of them would be *singular*, not plural).